# Android Wear error

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying out an Android wear project on syncing build.gradle I am getting below error.

```
Error:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77
```

Does this mean if I implement android wear for API 18 and more then I will not be able to support API 8 phones? (I know Android wear supports API 18 and more)

This is something strange...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 4.0 of Google Play Services, [froyo (API 8) is no longer supported](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html). That said, you have options. You can still build an app that uses the latest APIs in Google Play Services, but you must:

1. The error you're receiving is from the manifest merger - it sees that there's a discrepancy between the `uses-sdk` declaration in the manifest of Google Play Services, and the `min-sdk` declaration in your application's manifest - so it fails to merge them. Use the APIs available in the Gradle Manifest merger to force it to accept your value. I believe **Markers** is what you're looking for: [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger).
2. You **must** make sure, by checking `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` at runtime, that Froyo devices will not try to use any APIs in Google Play Services. This would cause a crash.

Comment: This worked for me: <uses-sdk tools:node="replace" android:minSdkVersion="8" />

Answer (score 1):

It means that your min-sdk must be set to 9, because one of your dependencies has a min-sdk of 9.

---

At the time of writing this, active devices with API8 make up 0.7% of all active devices.

[Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Comment: The dependency is the android wear..which is com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:5.0.77

Comment: yes. Probably Play Services in general from now - the docs say you need a device running 2.3 or above http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: The sample project in their website shows minimumSDK can be 8 and Google play service says minimum SDK should be 9.(Dependency for Android wear) This is really strange..